# How to access the data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, axios, javascript-objects

I'm accessing values of an object within an array within an object. Below is the format of the data:

```
 [{
    "id": "99a4e6ef-68b0-4cdc-8f2f-d0337290a9be",
    "stock_name": "Just Energy Group, Inc.",
    "shareholders": [{
        "userId": "e9328bb2-81ac-4e86-9ec8-520b1909cc9b",
        "number_of_shares": 266
    }, {
        "userId": "d42ff6a6-9b2f-4561-ac2e-0cf2bb170430",
        "number_of_shares": 389
    }]
}]
```

Below is my code to get data from github using axios and print out the user id:

```
const axios = require('axios')
require("util").inspect.defaultOptions.depth = null;
async function getStocks(){
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/graffixnyc/8c363d85e61863ac044097c0d199dbcc/raw/7d79752a9342ac97e4953bce23db0388a39642bf/stocks.json')
    return data // this will be the array of people objects
}
async function listShareholders() {
    let c=[]
    let a = await getStocks();
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        for(j=0;j<a[i].shareholders;j++)
            c.push((a[i].shareholders[j].userId))
    }
    return c 
    
}
async function bc(){
    const address = await listShareholders()
    console.log(address)
} 

bc()
```

Not sure why I get no output.

Comment: `j<a[i].shareholders` should be `j<a[i].shareholders.length`

Comment: Use `forEach()` and the code will be simpler and less error-prone.

Comment: Yea, I'm new to JS so need to get used to forEach(), but will try it out, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edited

*I'm editing to include the code from the original answer (not posted by me) that disappeared*

At `for(j=0;j<a[i].shareholders;j++)` you are comparing a `number` with an `Array`. This is the proper code:

```
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
     for(j=0; j < a[i].shareholders.length; j++)
         c.push((a[i].shareholders[j].userId);
}
```

#### My Answer

As pointed out at `for(j=0;j<a[i].shareholders;j++)` you are comparing a `number` with an `Array`.

The proposed solution works, but keep in mind that you can do it in one line:

```
const c = a.flatMap(obj => obj.shareholders.map(s => s.userId));
```